# Kusto Scan - how to deal with "optional" columns?

Tags: sequence, azure-data-explorer, kql

Can I use the SCAN operator to find sequences with values that occur only sporadically ?

Example use case: A computer raises a certain error message (B) in the boot phase (A to C). The error occurs only sporadically.

```
let Events = datatable (ts: datetime, Event: string) [
    datetime("2022-12-01"), "A", //Start
    datetime("2022-12-02"), "B", //An Error -  occurs only sometimes
    datetime("2022-12-03"), "C"  //End
]
;
Events
| sort by ts asc
| scan  with
(
    step s1: Event == "A";
    step s2: Event == "B"; 
    step s3: Event == "C";
)
```

With this code, scan would find C only if B exsists.
But I am searching for all sequences A to C, no matter if B occurs or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
let Events = datatable (ts: datetime, Event: string) [
    datetime("2022-12-01"), "A", //Start
    datetime("2022-12-02"), "B", //An Error -  occurs only sometimes
    datetime("2022-12-03"), "C"  //End
]
;
Events
| sort by ts asc
| scan with 
(
    step s1 : Event == "A";
    step s2 : Event in ("B", "C") and s2.Event != "C";
)
```

| ts | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | A |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | B |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | C |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WPwQ6CMBBE7/2KsSdIQKHeIBzU8AUejYcCjZJgMd1VY%20LHW0o0Xtyedt/sdGcwjPpuLBMqdJr9awaDiKmYWsP9xSSzogCx6%200pxkHA1wdHUmVKpblKs1zGCeRGJlit9qwd/xOqINwG4caidm50SIGxbW%20OMNrhCRovYY3%20mayDyU7Cm9S2E0dRijmLePltx2ie8ME0tdOg1RaPns8QUXAkNldQjmKOh6qaTi9/mPqy3iIK5/rvYmjbebic0aKahqWI37%20i5aBLAQAA)

Comment: You're welcome. Please make sure to close the cycle and accept the answer (mark the *V* symbol near the answer)